# Eclipse RCP application launcher not working properly in Arabic

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have an RCP application which I build using the .product file and PDE. In my product file I create a binary launcher for different applications to provide convenience to the user. It all works fine except when testing in Arabic languages.

In Arabic the application starts and it actually shows the Arabic characters that I mocked for testing but, it does not mirror.

That said, if I invoke the launcher and pass the -nl switch

launcher.exe -nl AR

Then it mirrors.

Also if I launch from the IDE with the target platform environment set to AR it mirrors too.

I am shipping the bidi plugins for jface and swt (along with the NL plugins) and for the platform delta packs...

Does anynone know what could be wrong with the laucher?

Answer (score 1):

The launcher itself does not set a value for -nl (or osgi.nl).  If it isn't set explicitly then the default is [`java.util.Locale#getDefault()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getDefault()).   The value there depends on the vm/os.   You may need to set the nl in the launcher.ini or config.ini files.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is a Eclipse/RCP bug

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=303889